# How filter condition working in spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in hbase with 1 billions records.I want to filter the records based on certain condition (by date).

For example:

```
Dataframe.filter(col(date) === todayDate)
```

Filter will be applied after all records from the table will be loaded into memory or I will get  filtered records?

Comment: On one hand, let's say that it depends on the data source that you are using. Sometimes the data source doesn't support all pushdown predicate. On other hand, your question is quite broad to answer considering all the data sources that spark can connect to e.g mongo, elasticsearch, hbase, cassandra, csv, etc.

Comment: I am trying to read the table from hbase by using spark hbase connector https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your use case is just read from storage, filter and save it somewhere and if you have some way to read data directly into RDD(that does the lazy load of records) then the filter will be pipelined with read and writes. That means the filter operation will not wait for whole data to be read[**In short, the filter is a transformation and not an action**]. If you have any actions before the filter then filter will be applied only after whole data is read from the store.

Comment: `If you have any actions before the filter then filter will be applied only after whole data is read from the store.` Actions are returning values, not RDDs, so you cannot `filter` result of action ;)

Comment: Like @T.Gawęda pointed out, your answer isn't accurate plus it doesn't really answer the OP's question.

Comment: @T.Gawęda I agree, But since the question is *Filter will be applied after all records from the table will be loaded into memory or I will get filtered records?*, that statement emphasizes the case when the whole data might be read. As per RDDs returning values, I agree with that. But considering the case where one calls rdd.count() and then rdd.filter(...) , my post answers the asked question.

Comment: @eliasah I believe above explanation explains why my post does answer the question. Please feel free to suggest any changes

Comment: In that case(considering your Github link in your comment), the filter will be applied in a pipeline manner. That means the filter will be applied as and when a record is read from the HBase table.